# Cookie Authentication on controllers with Windows and Forms Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Haven't found any really helpful articles or SO questions regarding this problem.

I want to behave my API in the following way:

- All controller actions should only be available for cookie authenticated users
- There are 2 login actions for getting a cookie by form (username/pw) or sso with the windows user (this is rather easy to do)

My problems with this currently:

- When the API returns 401 (the correct status code) for a controller action, the browser automatically defaults to re-triggering the request with a NTLM token. The user doesn't have a cookie and is still able to call the API action because the windows authentication scheme is still registered somehow
- It works as I want it to when I decorate ALL of the API actions with:

  [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

  In this case it seems that the Windows Authentication Scheme is never used but only cookies, which is what I want.
  I want this to be the only allowed behavior though without having to decorate all of the actions explicitly and never allow Windows Authentication Scheme (apart from the windows login action)

I can also kind of getting it working when I make sure that the Cookie Authentication doesn't return 401 but returns 403, which doesn't make the browser to re-trigger the request with NTLM authentication. This is a workaround at best though.

The relevant parts of Startup.cs currently look like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
            {
                opt.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            })
            .AddCookie(ConfigureApplicationCookie);
```

Cookie config:

```
private static void ConfigureApplicationCookie(CookieAuthenticationOptions options)
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
        options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
        options.LogoutPath = null;
        options.LoginPath = null;
    }
```

IIS (and IIS express) is configured to use Anonymous and Windows Authentication.

Comment: You need to remove integrated authentication in IIS for your website. Try this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/837139/how-to-disable-windows-integrated-authentication-for-web-sites-that-re)